# Getting mysterious build error in my universal 10 app

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am working on a universal 10 application,at first every thing works fine but after I get a strange error:

```
Processing Resources failed with error: double entrees
```

[image]

I tried to find some information on the internet, but nothing. Also when I double clicked on the error it doesn't bring me to the error's spot.

I have tried to do many things,like searching in the .resw file(s) and nothing helped, so I decided to write this post

Can someone help me resolve this errors?thanks for help

Comment: Do you have any duplicate resources in a resource dictionary?

Comment: I have searched in the .resw files (there any many files) I havn't seen any duplicate ressources,then,I have searched in the project for the MainPage.xbf (I have found it in bin/x64 and obg/x64) but I couldn't open it :(

Comment: XBF is a compiled XAML binary file - you won't be able to open it.

Comment: so Sir how can I resolve the problem :(

Comment: See my posted answer which will hopefully help you identify the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to indicate that you have a duplicate resource in a resource dictionary.

Try going through the resource dictionaries and removing any duplicates.

Another approach is to compare the source files you have now to ones that were previously compiling without any issues and see if you can narrow down the culprit.